# check if datetime variable is today, tomorrow or yesterday

Tags: datetime, dart

I do not know how to check if datetime variable is today, tomorrow or yesterday.

I did not find a method in the class members.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final today = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
final yesterday = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day - 1);
final tomorrow = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1);


final dateToCheck = ...
final aDate = DateTime(dateToCheck.year, dateToCheck.month, dateToCheck.day);
if(aDate == today) {
  ...
} else if(aDate == yesterday) {
  ...
} else(aDate == tomorrow) {
  ...
}
```

Hit: `now.day - 1` and `now.day + 1` works well with dates that result in a different year or month.

Answer (score 53):

While the above answer is correct, I would like to provide a more compact and flexible alternative :

```dart
/// Returns the difference (in full days) between the provided date and today.
int calculateDifference(DateTime date) {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  return DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day).difference(DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day)).inDays;
}
```

So if you want to check if `date` is :

- **Yesterday** : `calculateDifference(date) == -1`.
- **Today** : `calculateDifference(date) == 0`.
- **Tomorrow** : `calculateDifference(date) == 1`.

Comment: This has a flaw. If "the date you are checking" and "today's date"  has less than 24hours difference it will tell you the difference is 0 days, which is correct but  misleading. the dates are different but hours between does not exceed a day

Comment: By creating a new DateTime with only year, month and day we don't take hours into account.

Comment: There's another exception to this approach. If the two dates are from different timezones, the difference function will not take that into account. When dealing with UTC dates for server persistence and local timezone dates on the device, the comparison is not correct.

Answer (score 44):

Using dart extensions can help make your code more elegant. You can create a utility class with the following:

```
extension DateHelpers on DateTime {
  bool get isToday {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    return now.day == day && now.month == month && now.year == year;
  }

  bool get isYesterday {
    final yesterday = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
    return yesterday.day == day &&
        yesterday.month == month &&
        yesterday.year == year;
  }
}
```

And then whenever you need to know if a day is today or yesterday, import the utility class into the file where you need it and then call the appropriate function like it was inbuilt in the `DateTime` class.

```
Text(
    myDate.isToday() ? "Today" 
  : myDate.isYesterday() ? "Yesterday" 
  : DateFormat("dd MMM").format(myDate)
)
```

Comment: It could be a getter instead of a function, because we don't pass arguments but in overall this is the best answer 

Answer (score 18):

@34mo 's answer updated for flutter lint 2021

```
extension DateUtils on DateTime {
  bool get isToday {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    return now.day == day && now.month == month && now.year == year;
  }

  bool get isTomorrow {
    final tomorrow = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1));
    return tomorrow.day == day &&
        tomorrow.month == month &&
        tomorrow.year == year;
  }

  bool get isYesterday {
    final yesterday = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
    return yesterday.day == day &&
        yesterday.month == month &&
        yesterday.year == year;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

A simple `isToday` check:

```dart
/// Returns `true` if the [date] is today. Respects the time zone.
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/60213219/1321917
bool isToday(DateTime date) {
  final DateTime localDate = date.toLocal();
  final now = DateTime.now();
  final diff = now.difference(localDate).inDays;
  return diff == 0 && now.day == localDate.day;
}
```

Comment: This works best! I was getting issues with other answers regarding time zone. +1

Answer (score 0):

### Simple method to check if is today

```
   bool isToday(DateTime date) {
        final now = DateTime.now();

        return now.year == date.year &&
            now.month == date.month &&
            now.day == date.day;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For more simplification you can follow this steps.

> String myDate = **"01/09/2022"**;

like i need to check this "myDate" is today or tomorrow.

so,simply i call this function,

```
String dateConverter(String myDate) {
  String date;
  DateTime convertedDate =
      DateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY").parse(myDate.toString());
  final now = DateTime.now();
  final today = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
  final yesterday = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day - 1);
  final tomorrow = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1);

  final dateToCheck = convertedDate;
  final checkDate = DateTime(dateToCheck.year, dateToCheck.month, dateToCheck.day);
  if (checkDate == today) {
    date = "Today";
  } else if (checkDate == yesterday) {
    date = "Yesterday";
  } else if (checkDate == tomorrow) {
    date = "Tomorrow";
  } else {
    date = myDate;
  }
  return date;
}
```

if myDate is not today,tomorrow or yesterday then it simply return my default date string.

Answer (score -1):

This one will also do the work

```
 String checkDate(String dateString){

   //  example, dateString = "2020-01-26";

   DateTime checkedTime= DateTime.parse(dateString);
   DateTime currentTime= DateTime.now();

   if((currentTime.year == checkedTime.year)
          && (currentTime.month == checkedTime.month)
              && (currentTime.day == checkedTime.day))
     {
        return "TODAY";

     }
   else if((currentTime.year == checkedTime.year)
              && (currentTime.month == checkedTime.month))
     {
         if((currentTime.day - checkedTime.day) == 1){
           return "YESTERDAY";
         }else if((currentTime.day - checkedTime.day) == -1){
            return "TOMORROW";
         }else{
            return dateString;
         }

     }

 }
```