# want to show Date as today yesterday format in dart & flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating an app where i want to show 'today' and 'yesterday' instead of date

i have created this method but looks code is lengthy..

is there any other better way to make more advance level code? and is this code ok for it?

```
String? getDateAsString(DateTime date) {
  String result = '';
  DateTime today = DateTime.now();
  print(today.toString());
  DateTime yesterday = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1));
  print(yesterday.toString());

  if (date.year == today.year &&
      date.month == today.month &&
      date.day == today.day) {
    result = 'Today';
  
  } else {
    if (date.year == yesterday.year &&
        date.month == yesterday.month &&
        date.day == yesterday.day) {
      result = 'Yesterday';
    
    } else {
      result = DateFormat.MMMEd().format(date);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

void main() {
  DateTime date = DateTime(2023, 08, 12);

  print(getDateAsString(date));
}
```

Comment: Does [check if datetime variable is today, tomorrow or yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54391477/10157127) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
date.difference(DateTime.now()).inDays==0 // 0 for today and -1 for yesterday and 1 for tomorrow
```

Comment: The prettiest code you wrote. 

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution.

Source code:

```
String dateTimeFunction({required DateTime dateTime}) {
  final DateTime dtToday = DateTime.now();
  final DateTime dtYesterday = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

  return formatter.format(dateTime) == formatter.format(dtToday)
      ? "Hey it's Today ${formatter.format(dtToday)}"
      : formatter.format(dateTime) == formatter.format(dtYesterday)
          ? "Hey it's Yesterday ${formatter.format(dtYesterday)}"
          : "Hey it's Unknown ${formatter.format(dateTime)}";
}
```

Execution code

```
print(dateTimeFunction(dateTime: DateTime(2023, 08, 29)));
// Output: Hey it's Today 29-08-2023

print(dateTimeFunction(dateTime: DateTime(2023, 08, 28)));
// Output: Hey it's Yesterday 28-08-2023

print(dateTimeFunction(dateTime: DateTime(2023, 08, 27)));
// Output: Hey it's Unknown 27-08-2023
```

Comment: Beware: subtracting 1 day is always subtracting 24 hours, but some days have 23 and others have 25.  I did two videos on caution with Dart date math: https://youtu.be/usFSVUEadyo and https://youtu.be/LpoBYgzKVwU

Comment: So the DateTime class has year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond & microsecond. So, we should create a variable and only assign year, month, and day & we should fill the rest of the fields with 0s.

Comment: And be sure to do all date math in UTC, which doesn't have stupid daylight saving mistakes.